# Synchronously call ProcessEventsAsync to receive messages in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I have Windows Service written in C#, which is subscribing to Event hubs and listening to them for any messages.

The code I have followed is as follows:

```
public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    public Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{context.PartitionId}', Reason: '{reason}'.");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"SimpleEventProcessor initialized. Partition: '{context.PartitionId}'");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

    public Task ProcessErrorAsync(PartitionContext context, Exception error)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"Error on Partition: {context.PartitionId}, Error: {error.Message}");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
    {
       foreach (var eventData in messages)
       {
          var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);
          Console.WriteLine($"Message received. Partition: '{context.PartitionId}', Data: '{data}'");
          DoSomethingWithMessage(); // typically takes 20-20 mins to finish this method.
       }
       return context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the sample code mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host) document.

Now I have 8 partitions on my event hub. So 8 partitions keep receiving messages as and when there is a new message.  Whenever a message is received, a method is called `DoSomethingWithMessage()` which takes around 30 mins to finish as it does some calculations.

I want my code to run synchronously, meaning when one message is received, service should first complete this method execution, then receive the next message. Now what is happening is , even when the `DoSomethingWithMessage()` is still under execution, new messages are being received and that message is processed parallel to the first message, which is creating some calculation problems.

Is there a way I can receive messages one by one?

Comment: How many messages do you get per minute? If a single message takes 30 minutes to process and you want to process them one by one you might be better of using a queue. Event hub is for streaming and processing (tens of) thousands of messages per second.

Comment: Also, 8 partitions, what is the reason behind this choice as messages will be processed per partition?

Comment: @PeterBons We have 8 VMs where this windows service is installed. So 8 partitions. All the 8 VMs are subscribing to the same event hub. The typical messages we receive are 1-2 message every 10-15 mins. Not all of them takes 30 mins to process. It is the average time I have mentioned.

Comment: Also we are planning to change to kafka queue instead of event hubs, but that is not planned in the near future.

Comment: Ok. For now you what you can do is have al the event processor instances forward the messages to an azure storage/service bus queue and have one listener set up to process those messages.

Comment: @PeterBons , is there anything I can do from the code side instead of Infrastructure side?

Comment: Not easy to do. Each instance of the eventprocessor it attached to a single partition and lives in a separate process. So synchronizing a single queue using code will be hard.

Comment: By the way, do you want to process all the message in order, no matter which service send them? (like date&time send)

Comment: @PeterBons , yes. I want all of the messages to process in order , one after the other.

Comment: Then I am afraid you really are confronted with an I'll decision to go for event hub as it is not a good fit for ordered message processing. It is designed for scale and throughput. You can do ordered message processing per partition but without a lot of effort that is it. If all windows services write to a specific partition instead of using the default round robin distribution you can already do ordered processing per windows service. Otherwise not.

Comment: @PeterBons , Can you confirm my understanding on this. Each partition works as a separate thread and will receive messages simultaneously.  But with in a partition, we can process the messages one by one , is it?

Comment: Correct. But if the messages of a given windows service are send to different partitions (which is the default) it is hard to order those if that is the requirement

Comment: @PeterBons, I have another similar questions for which I have asked another question here :https://stackoverflow.com/q/60107379/8930751 as it is slightly different form my question here. Can you also refer to that question and answer please. Thanks.

Comment: You are running with the wrong service. Given long process duration and low message throughput, you should have been using Service Bus Queues, not Event Hubs.